# How to make xterm.js accept input?

Tags: javascript, terminal, xtermjs

I'm using xterm.js for a project but I can't get it to accept input. Whenever I try to type in the terminal nothing happens and there's no documentation or examples telling how to accomplish this.

This is what I have:

```
const term = new XTerm({
    cols: 100,
    cursorBlink: true,
    rows: 120
});
term.open(document.getElementById('terminal-window'), true)
term.fit()
term.writeln('Hello World!')
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

xtermjs is a library that expose an api, that allow us to build fully xterm based terminal emulator. But for every of the terminal functionalities you need to implement it through the api. Using the event listeners. And handling them. And combining it with others packages depend on what you want to achieve.

For input here are ways of doing it:

```
term.on('key', (key, ev) => {
        console.log(key.charCodeAt(0));
        if (key.charCodeAt(0) == 13)
            term.write('\n');
        term.write(key);
});
```

Another example to see how you need to manipulate and how you can achieve things is :

```
term.textarea.onkeypress = function (e) {
        term.write(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode));
}
```

here the link to the api, related to the terminal functionalities:
[https://xtermjs.org/docs/api/terminal/#onevent-callback`](https://xtermjs.org/docs/api/terminal/#onevent-callback)

you can for example clear the terminal using `term.clear();`

here an example that expose how the **on data event** work

```
term.on('data', (data) => {
        term.write(data);
   });
```

you will see that with that event, you can handle the data that is dispatched to the terminal. for instance when typing.

NOW sure this is all good. But that's not what gona help with a real app. To grasp better how things are i suggest the read of those articles and links:

- https://github.com/Tyriar/node-pty/blob/master/examples/electron/renderer.js
- https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/tree/master/demo
- http://hostiledeveloper.com/2017/05/02/something-useless-terminal-in-your-browser.html

to get you started right away! know that pty (pseudotty = pseudo terminal), here node-pty allow us to spawn a terminal process. and have an object that allow us to write to the terminal and so manipulate that terminal. then using xterm we will be able to write data to the pty and get data from the pty. (you can see it like this: the pty is the soul the real terminal that run. and xterm the body that allow us to expose that soul and so get to see.) both xterm and pty provide event on data. and it became as simple as that :

```
var os = require('os');
var pty = require('node-pty');
var Terminal = require('xterm').Terminal;

// Initialize node-pty with an appropriate shell
const shell = process.env[os.platform() === 'win32' ? 'COMSPEC' : 'SHELL'];
const ptyProcess = pty.spawn(shell, [], {
  name: 'xterm-color',
  cols: 80,
  rows: 30,
  cwd: process.cwd(),
  env: process.env
});

// Initialize xterm.js and attach it to the DOM
const xterm = new Terminal();
xterm.open(document.getElementById('xterm'));

// Setup communication between xterm.js and node-pty
xterm.on('data', (data) => {
  ptyProcess.write(data);
});
ptyProcess.on('data', function (data) {
  xterm.write(data);
});
```

see how the on data event are used. when something is wrote to ptyProcess. we write it in xterm. and when something is wrote on xterm we write it to the ptyProcess.
note that this is for an electron application. so all is straight forward!

Now if what you are doing isn't withing electron and that is a browser to server terminal. where xterm will live in the client and the processing will run on the server. which in that case using node-pty mean we will be using nodejs. then we need something in plus. and that the **websockets**. the principle stay the same, but we will need to link xterm and the pty through the websocket. That's it the idea. the example above provided in the **second link** express that very well. the project is in two part, the backend and the front end, main.js refer to the front end and app.js to the backend, and xterm will be in the main.js and app.js contain node-pty. pay attention to all what is done in that demo. I suggest to go all through it, to test things yourself, and also to run that same demo, to see and compare between what you simply achieve and what is different with the demo.

**Now third link**, a good article, where the backend isn't nodejs. Plus may be there is more details because it's a tutorial and not just a demo.
If not familiar with the back-end language here it's ok. that stay give a great idea on how you accomplish the work. Even though the first two links may suffice and more. after all are wrote by the one maintaining both projects.

**For the websockets and the principles it's as follow:**
you set a socket communication between the client and the server. you init the pty in the server. and xterm in the client. then in the server when ever the pty get data, you push that data to the client, where you take it and write it to xterm. And as the same in the client whenever xterm get data you send it to the server, where you get the data and write it to the pty. now that's at the all simple things. there is more details to it. like handling the columns and rows and re-dimension. the demo from the second link show very well that. 
Hope that get you started, and that is helpful.

if you are adventurous, looking at some project where such terminal where implemented there is no better, even such projects can be more complicated. To site some, there is visual studio code =>  search the project for node-pty. you will find your road. but here is where you need to go to cut it out: 
`src/vs/workbench/parts/terminal`.
there is hyper https://github.com/zeit/hyper.
and here the list for more projects:
https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/#real-world-uses

you can also load one of the sites that implement a terminal or an ide and try and see how they implemented xterm in the server side. it can give you a great deal of insight. example : https://aws.amazon.com/cloud9/

why you may need to look at more projects, it's about the affinity, and how you configure xterm, apply all the add-ons, manipulate the font, and resizing, search. and different things. Good luck! happy coding!

Comment: Thank you so much for including a simple node-pty integration example. It looks easy enough to bind to a shell :)

Comment: thank you. glade to hear that. the developers of those projects made it a breeze. Happy coding!

Comment: I'm really new to all this (I'm a C/C++/Java/Python developer) and struggling to get a hang of xterm.js Can you provide some kind of "complete recipe"? currently I am stuck to "require not found". I tried to add some lines in the `<head><script src="t>node_modules/node-pty"></script>...` but I got nowhere. Pointers would be welcome.

Comment: node-pty is a node module! And it's intended to be used server side! Part of nodejs! And require is the nodejs import function (commonjs modules)! You don't use it in the front end and HTML! (When it's electron one can use it!)
What are you trying to do ?

A terminal in a browser! Or you are using electron !?

Answer (score 19):

For the newer version (xterm.js 4.13), the API has been changed to the following:

```js
term.onKey(e => {
    console.log(e.key);
    term.write(e.key);
    if (e.key == '\r')
        term.write('\n');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

A more complete example that can handle: backspace, left & right arrows, inline edit. `simpleShell` function is an extended implementation of the answer [here](https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/issues/3050#issuecomment-1522403634):

```
let lineBuffer = [];
let history = [];
let shellListener = null;
let offset = 0;

async function simpleShell(data) {
    // string splitting is needed to also handle multichar input (eg. from copy)
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        const c = data[i];
        if (c === '\r') {  // <Enter> was pressed case
            offset = 0;
            term.write('\r\n');
            if (lineBuffer.length) {
                // we have something in line buffer, normally a shell does its REPL logic here
                // for simplicity - just join characters and exec...
                const command = lineBuffer.join('');
                lineBuffer.length = 0;
                history.push(command);
                try {
                    // tricky part: for interactive sub commands you have to detach the shell listener
                    // temporarily, and re-attach after the command was finished
                    shellListener?.dispose();
                    //await exec(command);  // issue: cannot force-kill in JS (needs to be a good citizen)
                } catch (e) {
                    // we have no real process separation with STDERR
                    // simply catch any error and output in red
                    const msg = !e ? 'Unknown Error...' : e.message || e;
                    term.write(`\x1b[31m${msg.replace('\n', '\r\n')}\x1b[m`);
                } finally {
                    // in any case re-attach shell
                    shellListener = term.onData(simpleShell);
                }
            }
            term.write('> ');
        } else if (c === '\x7F') {  // <Backspace> was pressed case
            if (lineBuffer.length) {
                if (offset === 0) {
                    lineBuffer.pop();
                    term.write('\b \b');
                }
                else if (offset < 0 && Math.abs(offset) !== lineBuffer.length) {
                    var insert = "";

                    for (var ci = lineBuffer.length + offset; ci < lineBuffer.length; ci++) {
                        insert += lineBuffer[ci];
                    }

                    lineBuffer.splice(lineBuffer.length + offset - 1, 1);

                    var lefts = "";
                    
                    for (var ci = 0; ci < insert.length; ci++) {
                        lefts += '\x1b[1D';
                    }
                    
                    var termInsert = '\b \b' + insert + ' ' + '\b \b' + lefts;
                    term.write(termInsert);
                }
            }
        } else if (['\x1b[A', '\x1b[B', '\x1b[C', '\x1b[D'].includes(data.slice(i, i + 3))) {  // <arrow> keys pressed
            if (data.slice(i, i + 3) === '\x1b[A') {
                // UP pressed, select backwards from history + erase terminal line + write history entry
            } else if (data.slice(i, i + 3) === '\x1b[B') {
                // DOWN pressed, select forward from history + erase terminal line + write history entry
            }
            else if (data.slice(i, i + 3) === '\x1b[C') {
                if (offset < 0) {
                    term.write('\x1b[1C');
                    offset++;
                }
            }
            else if (data.slice(i, i + 3) === '\x1b[D') {
                if (Math.abs(offset) < lineBuffer.length) {
                    term.write('\x1b[1D');
                    offset--;
                }
            }

            i += 2;
        } else {  // push everything else into the line buffer and echo back to user
            
            var insert = "";
            insert += c;

            for (var ci = lineBuffer.length + offset; ci < lineBuffer.length; ci++) {
                insert += lineBuffer[ci];
            }

            var shift = "";
            
            if (offset < 0) {
                for (var ci = lineBuffer.length + offset; ci < lineBuffer.length; ci++) {
                    shift += "\x1b[1D";
                }
            }
            
            if (offset === 0) {
                lineBuffer.push(c);   
            }
            else if (offset < 0) {
                lineBuffer.splice(lineBuffer.length + offset, 0, c);
            }
            
            var termInsert = insert;
            
            if (offset < 0) {
                termInsert += shift;
            }
            
            term.write(termInsert);
        }
    }
}

shellListener = term.onData(simpleShell);
```

Expects `term` variable to be defined as in the other answers.